# Blue screen after installing GNOME 3 Desktop

Tags: 14.04, gnome, openbox

I installed GNOME 3, after testing it a bit I decided to return using Unity and Openbox. Unity works great but when I use Openbox there is a sort of "blue screen" over my desktop. I've no way to show that, tried screenshotting desktop but it appears clean.
Any way to solve this issue?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Hah? The blue screen IS openbox.